# Flash content linkable

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Is there a way to make flash content open a new tab to a link specified once clicked using either javascript or HTML?

I tried many ways but cannot seem to make this work and Flash content itself is not clickable to a link

Comment: please post what u tried

Comment: @Jae: We can call JavaScript from flash so you can use the window.open to open a new window. What is the problem in doing like that?

Comment: $('#flashContent').click(function(){window.open('http://lgjobs.com.au');}); This is not working on some browsers such as older versions of Firefox and IE

Answer (score 1):

Flash content **can** have clickable links, so using JavaScript or HTML may not be necessary.

The ActionScript 3 function `flash.net.navigateToURL(request:URLRequest, window:String)` can be used to open webpages exactly like links do. The argument `window` specifies which window to open the page in (`"_self"` for the same page, `"_blank"` in a new window or tab).

For example, in ActionScript 3:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void {
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com");
    flash.net.navigateToURL(url, "_blank");
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html

Comment: I know but the problem is I don't have access to the source code. Can we use javascript to have links instead?